# How to integrate Google calendar by jquery mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-calendar-api

Please let me know how to integrate google calender in application by jquery mobile..is any api is there to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can find the Google Calendar API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). You can simply use jQuery AJAX requests to fetch data from Google, parse it and display the result on your jQuery Mobile page.